# Use singular or plural third person for gustar + multiple infinitives

Tags: uso-de-palabras, plurales

Which of the two below is correct?

```
1: Me gusta correr y esquiar.
2: Me gustan correr y esquiar.
```

Answer (score 4):

Infinitives technically agree in the singular, no matter how many are chained together.  The reason is a rather complex and not guaranteed (in certain contrastive situations they may still be considered as plural, and that is even more likely so preverbally).  This is not unique for *gustar*, in fact, but true for any verb or adjective that needs to agree with some infinitives.

Answer (score 2):

> Which of the two below is correct?
>
> 1: Me gusta correr y esquiar.
>
> 2: Me gustan correr y esquiar.

Only sentence (1) above is correct.

Just to expand on what guifa correctly answered, below are some sources and examples which confirm that coordinated infinitives in subject position will take a singular verb unless they are presented as contrasting with each other:

Source: http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5

c) Si los elementos coordinados son gramaticalmente neutros, como infinitivos, oraciones sustantivas o pronombres neutros, el verbo va en singular: «No creo que **sumar y restar sea** lo suyo» (Sierra Regreso [Esp. 1995]) [...]; pero si los elementos neutros coordinados se conciben o presentan en el enunciado como realidades diferenciadas, contrastadas o enfrentadas, el verbo irá en plural: «**Informar y opinar son** los dos fines específicos y diferenciales del periodismo» (MtzAlbertos Noticia [Esp. 1978]).

Source: https://www.um.es/tonosdigital/znum15/secciones/estudios-24.htm

d) Dos o más infinitivos, como neutros que son, concuerdan en singular, como en:

“**Madrugar, hacer ejercicio, y comer moderadamente, es** provechosísimo para la salud.” (Bello 1981: 503)

(According to the author, the verbs *getting up early, doing exercise* and *eating healthily* form a single idea and thus agree with the verb in the singular. However, if the verbs are nominalized by means of an article, they agree with the verb in the plural:)

“**El madrugar, el hacer ejercicio, y el comer moderadamente son** provechosísimos para la salud.” (Bello 1981: 503)

As guifa said, the position of the verb may dictate which form, singular or plural, will be adopted even if the infinitives are opposites, as is the case with *lazing around* and *learning*. If the infinitives precede the verb, the verb will take the plural form, but the singular may be used if they follow it:

“**Holgazanear y aprender son** incompatibles”

“No **se compadecía tener** oración **y andar** tan llena de imperfecciones y faltas” (Yebes, Vida de Santa Teresa, I, 6)[RAE 1973: 391). (Here, "compadecían" could also be used. However, in the examples below only the singular is grammatically correct:)

“Me **gusta**/*gustan **bailar y cantar**.” ("gustan" is incorrect)

“**Es** imposible/*son imposibles **holgazanear y aprender**.” ("son" is incorrect)

Comment: I think I'm going to do an entire question with self answer on the subject of the neuter, as it's a concept that no one talks about in most Spanish classes yet has some pretty big and unexpected consequences in grammar at times.